# Почему WebProxy / request.Proxy тормозит программу?

Tags: c#, proxy

Написал (для себя, изучаю программирование на C#) парсер html, с таким функционалом: сначала собирает ссылки на на сайте, затем запрашивает по ссылкам страницы, и текстовое содержимое сохраняет в csv, а найденные картинки в файлы.

Работает довольно шустро, пока не добавляешь в запрос прокси, вот такой кусок кода:

```
  WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(proxies[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxies[1]));
  request.Proxy = wp;
```

Результат: программа выполняется **заметно медленнее**, чем без .Proxy, при этом еще и не все найденное сохраняет (не все картинки, и не все строки);

в другом варианте  (в данном случае хост взят отсюда free-proxy-list.net), выполнение просто останавливается:

```
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("5.141.9.86", 8080);
request.Proxy = wp;
```

**Что это за особенности класса WebProxy? В чем может быть причина?**

Это весь метод запроса html:

```
public static string DownloadHtml(string uri, Encoding encoding, List<string> goodUrlsList)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int z = rnd.Next(0, goodUrlsList.Count);
    string prox = goodUrlsList[z];

    string [] proxies = prox.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(proxies[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxies[1]));
    request.Proxy = wp;

    request.UserAgent = ParserVirgo.Utils.UserAgent.userAgent();
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.KeepAlive = true;

    // получаем ответ
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    // данные
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
    sr.ReadLine();
    string html = sr.ReadToEnd();

    // получаем чтмл
    return html;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прокси - это дополнительный сервер, через который проходит запрос. Если сам сайт отвечает за 0.1с, а прокси при этом тупит 1с, то общее время с использованием прокси будет 1.1с.

А если прокси не захочет отвечать - то ваш код будет ждать от него ответа до истечения таймаута ("вобще подвисать").

Запускайте закачку данных сразу в несколько потоков, через несколько прокси - тогда в каждый момент времени хотя бы один из них успеет оттупить, и начать отдавать данные. Те прокси, что вообще не отвечают - вычеркивайте из списка.

И не забудьте в конфиг своего приложения добавить

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
 <system.net> 
  <connectionManagement> 
   <add address="*" maxconnection="100" /> 
  </connectionManagement> 
 </system.net> 
</configuration>
```

по умолчанию в .net установлен лимит в два одновременных исходящих http запроса на один домен - что достаточно безполезно при массовом дампе контента всего сайта.

Comment: *по умолчанию в .net установлен лимит в два одновременных исходящих http запроса* **на один домен**

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, спасибо наверное стоит уточнить - у топикастера нет ротации проксей, судя по всему, и дампит он один сайт

Comment: Уверен про лимит? Там вроде всего 4 соединения было, правда необходимости качать с разных доменов одновременно у меня не возникало.

Comment: @Qwertiy [более чем](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=VS.100).aspx) -  The default value is 2. При выполнении под ASP.NET рантайм выставляет чуть побольше (то ли 10, то ли 12 * CPU)

Answer (score 1):

Это не особенности WebProxy, это особенности того прокси-сервера, который вы используете.

Comment: ну я подставляю из списка в случайном порядке, а источник  тут http://webanetlabs.net/publ/24

как это лечить?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете установить на `Request` таймаут и в случае ошибки использовать другой прокси для того же запроса. Задать таймаут можно так:

```
request.Timeout = 60000;
```